# Why is jvm heap memory not used completely?

Tags: java, linux, jvm, out-of-memory, heap-memory

My application launches many threads to receive and send data, I got out of memory error, I decided to increase the heap so that the application finishes the process before having the out of memory problem.

```
   java -Xmx5120M -jar peer100.jar config

}catch ( OutOfMemoryError  e) {
        System.out.println("out of memory");
        MemoryUsage heapUsage = memoryBean.getHeapMemoryUsage();
        long MEGABYTE = 1024*1024;
        long maxMemory = heapUsage.getMax() / MEGABYTE;
        long usedMemory = heapUsage.getUsed() / MEGABYTE;   
        System.out.println(" : Memory Use :" + usedMemory + "M/" + maxMemory + "M");

        System.exit(0);

    }
```

when I checked the usage of the memory I found that the heap is not used as I expected

```
: Memory Use :16M/4551M
```

is there any solution to work with overall size of the heap ?

Comment: I am quite sure the problem here is more in your way of measuring heap usage (or more the point where you do so)

Comment: Consider using a memory profiler if you actually want to get reasonable results for heap usage measurement :)

Comment: what do you think about giving a high value for heap size and having the same problem in case we don't specify any heap size ?

Comment: You can't say that the memory usage you printed shows the info when error occured. you should monitor your heap memory usage. you can use jstat and share the results. jstat -gc <PID> | tail -n 1 | awk '{split($0,a," "); sum=a[3]+a[4]+a[6]+a[8]; print sum}'

Comment: is there any solution to manage the heap before it gets fully used ?

Comment: You should check the message string of the OOME, it's not always a heap space issue